# Error installing Blitz php.h not found

Tags: php, mamp-pro

Following the installation instructions on http://alexeyrybak.com/blitz/blitz_en.html I get an error on the last step `make install`

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/lib/php/blitz-0.8.14/blitz.c:30:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found
#include "php.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [blitz.lo] Error 1
```

I'm installing on  MAMP Pro on Mac 10.10.

Grateful for any pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to install Blitz in MAMP, you need to download the php sources and run the blitz installation with those sources. Here's how:

1. Follow steps 1-5 from the helpful guys at [Extreme Creations](http://www.extreme-creations.co.uk/blog/how-to-install-phalcon-php-framework-with-mamp-on-osx/)
2. Run phpize referring to the MAMP php version you're using:
   `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.X.X/bin/phpize`
3. Run ./config referring to that php version too:
   `./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.X.X/bin/php-config`
4. Then `make install` as usual

I hope that helps someone :)

An additional mention and thank you to [Alexey A. Rybak](http://alexeyrybak.com/blitz/blitz_en.html) the author of Blitz who answered my emails within a few minutes and put me on the right path to solving the problem. Thanks!